# Attribute changeable by animation and accesible by [attribute=value]

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am currently trying to make an animation that changes an attribute which can be accessed by [attribute=value] like so:

```
.test {
Animation: someAnimation 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes someAnimation{
    20% {someAttribute: someValue;}
    40% {someAttribute: someValue;}
}
.test[someAttribute=someValue]{
background-color: red;
}
```

What would SomeAttribute be if anything?

Note: I am explicitly looking for the background-color to be changed by accessing `SomeAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

You can target element in CSS with attributes, but you can change them. For that you need javascript.

```css
.test-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

[data-pickMe="true"] {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-element" data-pickMe="true">Test</div>
```